# java.lang.IllegalStateException: [TextView] must not be null

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin

I am trying to display two values that are obtained from a SQL query and present the values inside the TextViews.

```
   barcode_field_value3.text = BarcodeProcessor.data.value1
   barcode_field_value2?.text = BarcodeProcessor.data.value2
```

I know value1 & value2 have the correct values because I print them to the console and they are correct each time.

In my LiveBarcodeScanningActivity I tried putting the above statements inside the onCreate() but it crashes right when the app launches the activity.

I have another section below where I tried to change the text values:

```
    workflowModel?.detectedBarcode?.observe(this, Observer { barcode ->

            if (barcode != null) {
                val barcodeFieldList = ArrayList<BarcodeField>()
                barcodeFieldList.add(BarcodeField("Module Serial #",   barcode.rawValue ?: ""))
                BarcodeResultFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, barcodeFieldList)

    //This prints the values to the console as a test
                println("This is the RESULTS ---- " + BarcodeProcessor.data.value1)
                println("This is the RESULTS ---- " + BarcodeProcessor.data.value2)

            }
            barcode_field_value3.text = BarcodeProcessor.data.value1
            barcode_field_value2?.text = BarcodeProcessor.data.value2
        })
```

I tried making the values nullable but nothing ever changes when they are.

#### BarcodeResultFragment

```
/** Displays the bottom sheet to present barcode fields contained in the detected barcode.  */
/**
 * Controls the bottom slide in (barcode_field.xml)
 */
class BarcodeResultFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        layoutInflater: LayoutInflater,
        viewGroup: ViewGroup?,
        bundle: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.barcode_bottom_sheet, viewGroup)

        val arguments = arguments
        val barcodeFieldList: ArrayList<BarcodeField> =
            if (arguments?.containsKey(ARG_BARCODE_FIELD_LIST) == true) {
                arguments.getParcelableArrayList(ARG_BARCODE_FIELD_LIST) ?: ArrayList()
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "No barcode field list passed in!")
                ArrayList()
            }

        view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.barcode_field_recycler_view).apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = BarcodeFieldAdapter(barcodeFieldList)
        }

        return view
    }

    override fun onDismiss(dialogInterface: DialogInterface) {
        activity?.let {
            // Back to working state after the bottom sheet is dismissed.
            ViewModelProviders.of(it).get<WorkflowModel>(WorkflowModel::class.java)
                .setWorkflowState(WorkflowState.DETECTING)
        }
        super.onDismiss(dialogInterface)
    }

    companion object {

        private const val TAG = "BarcodeResultFragment"
        private const val ARG_BARCODE_FIELD_LIST = "arg_barcode_field_list"

        fun show(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, barcodeFieldArrayList: ArrayList<BarcodeField>) {
            val barcodeResultFragment = BarcodeResultFragment()
            barcodeResultFragment.arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putParcelableArrayList(ARG_BARCODE_FIELD_LIST, barcodeFieldArrayList)
            }


            barcodeResultFragment.show(fragmentManager, TAG)
        }

        fun dismiss(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
            (fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG) as BarcodeResultFragment?)?.dismiss()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put your code inside the if condition. At the end of condition.

Comment: It still crashes the app when the code is inside the if block

Comment: may be you are getting the values but you haven't initialized your text view barcode_field_value3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
val requestCode=100


startActivityForResult(Intent(context,MainActivity::class.java),requestCode)
```

and In barcode scanner activity

```
 val data =  Intent();
    val text = "Result to be returned...."
//---set the data to pass back---
    data.setData("Your Data");
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
//---close the activity---
    finish()
```

and get in main activity like this

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data:Intent):Void {
if (requestCode == requestCode) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error says "barcode_field_value3 must not be null".
Verify the code is running only after you've initialized the barcode_field_value3 member

Answer (score 1):

In fragment you have to use widget like this

```
view.barcode_field_value3.text=
view.barcode_field_value2.text=
```

Here view is the main layout and declare it in onCreateView like this

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false)
```

Comment: I added the BarcodeResultFragment above. Even when I try to set the barcode_field_value3.text is still gives me the (cannot be null) error.

Comment: I think your fragment's show method called before initializing, Please let me know exact flow like why are you switching from activity to fragment?

Comment: barcode_field_value3 this field belongs to activity or fragment?

Comment: barcode_field_Value3 is on a bottom sheet, that will slide in when a barcode has been scanned with the values. So from the main activity when a button is pressed we go to the scanner activity that looks for a barcode and scans it. Then a slide in pops up to display results (im assuming that is the fragment?) The barcode fields are on that slide in. Then it will be dismissed and we can go to scan another barcode.

Comment: Is it possible to initialize the barcode_field_values from the companion object inside the fragment class?

Comment: can we finish scanner activity and pass scanned value to main activity and in onActivityResult we can display it's value? if you understand i will send you code

Comment: I believe we can. In my barcodeProcessor file after retrieving the values from the sql query I send them to the main in a object where I can display the correct results to the console.

Comment: try my new answer , revert me if there is any problem. Please try once

Comment: I will try and let you know, Thank you

Comment: I keep getting an error (barcode_field_value3 must not be null)

Comment: barcode_field_value3  this field is in mainactivity right?

Comment: Have you added this line apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' in build.gradle app level?

Comment: I have added that plugin yes. The barcode_field_vvalue3 is in the fragment I believe. Its its own .xml that will be called

Comment: but I think you don't need fragment!  barcode_field_vvalue3 must be in activity

Comment: As per my understanding you have 2 activities main and barcodeScanner. correct?

Comment: Yes I was able to solve the issue with the code you had provided